# php\mysql not selecting all rows (php issue)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to SELECT all rows as specified in the query below, but I think the issue is related to mysql_fetch_row, because in MYSQL Workbench the MYSQL query (yes I know I should be using PDO) shows all desired rows.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zebra_id FROM zebra WHERE user_id = '$id' AND pref = '1'")
or die(mysql_error());
$array =  mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo json_encode($array);
```

JSON Output (only showing 1 row):

```
["986"]
```

I tried changing to mysql_fetch_array, but that doesn't output all rows in the JSON encoded $array.

Comment: a bit off topic, but you could have an `animals` table, with a column for `animalType`. Might cut down on the coding.

Comment: You need to call mysql_fetch_row in a loop to get the next record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_row()` only fetchs *one row* as the name implies. So your error is obvious.

`mysql_fetch_array()` won't work unless you iterrate through the entire result set*. You just don't call it once and expect to get the entire result set in an array.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zebra_id FROM zebra WHERE user_id = '$id' AND pref = '1'")
or die(mysql_error());
$array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in a loop. See this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT zebra_id FROM zebra WHERE user_id = '$id' AND pref = '1'")
or die(mysql_error());
$array = array();
while($row =  mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    $array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array);
```

And also I have to say that, do not use mysql_* functions anymore. These are deprecated officially. You have to use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Comment: I'll have to research loops. I'm ashamed to not know this.

Comment: Wrap your loop in brackets, Omitting them is poor form even if syntactically valid.

Comment: Bad Coding practice to not use brackets.